# Jboss Central - to many icons in Eclipse workspace

Tags: eclipse, jboss-tools

My Eclipse workspace contains four icons of Jboss Central. 
How can I clear them?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest moving up to the latest Eclipse Neon.3 and Devstudio 10.4.

Or try restarting Eclipse with `./eclipse -clean -debug -console -consolelog` to get more information on why you have multiple instances of Central running.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Eclipse? Which version of JBoss Tools or Red Hat JBoss Developer Studio are you running? Can you attach a screenshot to a JIRA report, with more details, and assign it to me (nickboldt / nboldt) ?

If you're running JBoss Tools: https://issues.jboss.org/projects/JBIDE
If you're running Devstudio: https://issues.jboss.org/projects/JBDS

Comment: nickboldt, question updated. See attached screenshots for more details it the topic. Eclipse 4.4.2